# How to get value inside <td> which is inside tr[2] by finding a text whose <th> is inside tr[1] using java

Tags: java

I am new to selenium and I need to get the value £1000 which is inside

```
td  class='ng-ngclass' /td
```

and i need to find that by finding text `'Wrapper1'` from

```
th class="ng-ngclass" colspan="3" - Wrapper1 - /th
```

I should pass the text `'Wrapper1'` in `%s` in the below constant

I've tried the below one
`private static final String WRAPPER_VALUE = "//th[@class='ng-ngclass'`and `contains(text(), %s)]` and `//td[@class='ng-ngclass']"` in FirePath but it is returning me 1 number: `NaN` in firefox console.. What does that really mean?

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="summaryEncash" class="body scroll-body" ng-class="  {clsOnlyAdPlan: hasOverview === false}">
<!-- ngRepeat: asset in assetTypes -->
<table class="data-stripe ng-scope" ng-repeat="asset in assetTypes" analytics="homePortfolioTap" ng-click="showAssetDetail(0)" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr ng-show="isCurrentValue">
<th class="ng-ngclass" colspan="3">Wrapper1</th>
</tr>
<tr class="summary-value" ng-show="isCurrentValue">
<td class="ng-ngclass">£1000</td>
<td/>
<td class="arrow">
<i class="next next-arrow"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but this appears to be JavaScript and not Java. Using the correct tags improves your chances of getting good help.

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath expression `//td[@class='ng-ngclass']` returns the `td` element with its text node.

The Xpath expression `//td[@class='ng-ngclass']/text()` should return the text value of `td` element. So the string `£1000`.  Then you have to parse it to get a number.

Comment: Thanks :) i tried your suggested one in firepath now in the matching node console it is saying me 1 Number.. and the number is NaN @phico

Comment: Is that returning me the number required.. i need not get the parsed number i just need £1000. Can anyone say the meaning of NaN? @phico

Comment: Depending of the parser used, the expression //td[@class='ng-ngclass']/text() should return a string value or an object.  So it is not a number (NaN means Not a Number).  Print it to know the type returned and then parse it or get the string value out of it.